# FormattedNumber do intl-react trocar ponto por vírgula

Tags: react, internacionalização

Olá pessoal no meu código está da seguinte forma

```
const currencyFormatter = (value: string | number | ReactText[]) => {
    return (
        <FormattedNumber
         value={Number(value)}
         style='currency'
         currency='BRL'
         minimumFractionDigits={2}
         maximumFractionDigits={2}
        />      
    );
  }
```

Entretanto o valor retornado é:

`R$4,567.42`

Mas, o certo seria `R$ 4.567,42` .

Alguém já fez a correção/formatação nesse estilo?

Comment: Eu particularmente nunca utilizei esse pacote, mas caso você queira simplesmente formatar o valor, da pra fazer dessa forma: `new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }).format(4567.42)`

Comment: Eu até já usei esse, funciona bem, entretanto, estou seguindo o padrão solicitado pelo cliente que é usar este pacote! :(

Comment: Essa [extensao](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl-currency-input) ajuda?

Answer (score -1):

Amigo tente utilizar a propriedade do JavaScript, utilizando a função .toLocaleString()

Segue abaixo uma explicação de como utilizar e o que deve ser feito.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString